# I don’t understand why “reticence” = « la réticence » and why “reticent” = « réticent(e) »

Tags: noms

So the definition of **reticent** is [“to be unwilling to talk about your thoughts or feelings”](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reticent) and the definition of **reticence** is [“the unwillingness to do sth or talk about sth”](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reticence?q=Reticence).

**HOWEVER**

The definition of « la reticence » est

1. [Omission délibérée ce que l'on pourrait ou devrait dire (= the deliberate omission of what one could or should say).](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9R2208)

and

2. [l’attitude de qn qui hésite à dire expressément sa pensée (= the attitude of sb who hesitated to say his thought with a well defined intention.](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/r%C3%A9ticence/68844)

Lastly, [if qqn est réticent alors cette personne manifeste de la réticence.](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/reticent)

I’ve chosen to learn the words « la réticence » and « réticent(e) » and I’m happy memorising the definitions given by the French dictionaries. Also, because Collins dictionary is saying that **[reticence = la réticence](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/reticence) and [reticent = réticent(e)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/reticent)**, I’ll also memorise this. But honestly, by reading the French and English definitions, I’m not convinced that **reticence = la réticence and reticent = réticent(e)**.

Am I wrong to say that Collins dictionary is wrong here, that **reticence ≠ la réticence and reticent ≠ réticent(e)**?

Comment: The Academy's dictionary, despite its institutional clout, is quite garbage. You're better off referring to the TLFi (https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9ticence or even to the modern commercial dictionaries like Robert or Larousse

Answer (score 2):

The Collins definition would perfectly apply to the French *réticent* and *réticence*.

I wouldn't blame the Cambridge dictionary then for the discrepancies but more the *Dictionnaire de l'Académie* who condemns the usual meaning and defends a forgotten one.